# String PHP em Alert Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Como posso pegar o retorno de uma banco de dados em PHP e jogar o resultado em um `alert` javascript ?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
 // Print out the contents of each row into a table
 $nome = $row['Nome'];
 echo "<tr><td>"; 
 echo $row['id'];
 echo "</td><td>"; 
 echo $nome;
 echo "</td></tr>"; 

 echo '<script language="javascript">';
 echo 'alert("message successfully sent")'; <------- INSERIR A VARIÁVEL ( $Nome ) AQUI DENTRO
 echo '</script>';

}
```

Comment: `echo 'alert("message successfully sent '.$Nome.'")'` ou `sprintf('alert("message successfully sent %s")', $Nome)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta concatenar, assim:

```
 echo 'alert("message successfully sent '.$nome.'");';
```

Apenas tome cuidado com conflitos de caracteres reservados do JavaScript. Exemplo, se a string provinda do PHP possuir double quote (aspa dupla), agirá como uma injeção XSS

Exemplo de conflito:

```
$nome = 'nome "com aspa"';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent '.$nome.'");';
```

resultará em `alert("message successfully sent nome "com aspa"");`, provocando erro de sintaxe JavaScript.

Para dar consistência ao código, passe a string php dentro da função [addslashes()](http://php.net/addslashes)

```
$nome = 'nome "com aspa"';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent '.addslashes($nome).'");';
```

Retornará `alert("message successfully sent nome \"com aspa\"");`

Como as aspas estão escapadas, o erro de sintaxe no JavaScript é evitado.

Comment: Que legal e se caso o Alert java script estivesse fora de <?php ?>, teria como inserir a uma variável PHP ? Tem como fazer uma variável global em PHP ?

Comment: Nesse caso bastaria fazer assim: `alert("message successfully sent <?php echo $nome;?>");`